# Understanding design with polymorphism (C++)

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Coming from my background in dynamic languages, I find I have a problem expressing my intentions in a statically-typed language such as C++.

I'm designing a preference system for my application. As every preference will have a few associated values (the default value, limits, an observer function...) I decided to encapsulate each preference in an object of its own. Here's my first draft:

```
class Preference    // purely abstract class
{
    parseFromString(String s) = 0;
    get() = 0;
    void set(newVal) = 0;
private:
    // internal data
};
```

Now I need to create a few derived classes, like `IntPreference`, `FloatPreference` and `StringPreference`. Here's how their declaration would look like:

```
class IntPreference : Preference          class StringPreference : Preference
{                                         {
    int parseFromString(String s);            String parseFromString(String s);
    void set(int newVal);                     void set(String newVal);
    // etc.                                   // etc.
}                                         }
```

Now that the `set()` method takes an `int` parameter in the class `IntPreference` and a `String` parameter in `StringPreference`, there's no way to declare this function in the base class. The same goes with the return value of `parseFromString()`. I understand this is impossible to do in C++, because functions with the same name and different parameter types in a derived class just overshadow, not override their ancestors. Again, this is how I would express myself in a dynamic language, what's the correct pattern in C++?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to mention I need a base class to store them all in a hash table:

```
Hash(const char *name, Preference pref);
```

Comment: How would you actually use your polymorphic methods? Wouldn't you have to know what kind of preference it was before you could correctly make the method call?

Comment: Maybe it's too simple, but - are you looking for [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29)?

Comment: You probably want to implement (a) container class(es), in which there are unions. Then you can simply declare the methods to take instances of that container class.

Comment: Please note that members of a `class` is be default private, so the methods are not callable from outside the class. You might want to add `public:` before declaring the methods.

Comment: Use templates like Jakob said or create a base class of all supported parameters (int, string) and use that or simply use void* - which is pretty dynamic, I suppose. Void* is not really the C++ way though, as I understand it?!

Comment: Just as a curiosity, in which way do you plan to retrieve values from the hash table?

Comment: Now that all you folks advise me to avoid class hierarchy at all, another thing comes to my mind: Would it be wise to create an empty parent class `class Preference {}` just to facilitate the storage in a hash table?

Comment: @CoffeeonMars - This is what I came up with: `int val = preference["name"].get()`, `preference["name"].set(newVal)`. ;-) Maybe too complex, but I'm using Qt and I wanted to `connect(preference["name"], SIGNAL(changed()), myobject, SLOT(prefChanged())`. Also, if a preference contains an array of values (geometry preference, color preference) this would make things quite easier. `pref["name"].getR(); pref["name"].getG(); pref["name"].getB();` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have now, is a poor `boost::any` class and you maybe should
simply just use that.

Your `parseFromString()` member function is dubious. You use the
dynamic type to decide what to parse out of the string, something that
always has to be known statically.

```
class my_any {
public:
  template<typename T>
  explicit // don't rely on conversions too much
  my_any(const T& t) : x_(t) {}

  // might throw if the cast fails
  template<typename T>
  T& get() { return boost::any_cast<T&>(x_); }

  // also maybe move semantics
  template<typename T>
  set(const T& t) { x_ = t; }
private:
  boost::any x_;
};

// usage:
my_any m;
m.set(23);
try {
  int& x = m.get<int>();
catch(boost::bad_any_cast& ex) {
  // ...
}

// for setting things from string just do 
// the right thing at the call site of set
```

If you dislike templates you can simply provide a few defaults:

```
my_any::getInt(); my_any::getString();
```

**EDIT**: If `boost::any` is too generic for you and you want to limit
your construct to a certain set of values use
`boost::variant`. Although a variant has a larger impact on compile
time and can be quite hard to use for a beginner.

**EDIT2**: The hash table problem:

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, my_any> preference_table;
preference_table t;
// i added a template constructor to my_any
t.insert(std::make_pair("Foobar", my_any(23)));
```

Comment: That's nice! I did not know `boost::any`.

Answer (score 2):

Woah - slow down there!  You have a *strongly typed* language.  That's not a design flaw, it's deliberate: it's meant to be a little restrictive so it can do compilation-time checks on your program's correctness and produce much faster, cleaner code.  Please do not go out of your way to throw away type safety by creating some type-ambiguous interface!  There's nothing in your question to suggest you have any need to do so.

Consider doing something like:

```
struct Config
{
    int max_for_whatever_;
    string name_for_whatever_;
    double scaling_factor_for_whatever_else_;
    bool verbose_;
};
```

As you parse the inputs, you can populate the specific related member variable.

Now, there's lots of good libraries to do that.  The leading general-purpose C++ 3rd-party library is "boost", which has argument parsing facilities.  And while some C++ compilers ship with enhanced versions of this (specifically, the GNU C++ compiler has an extended `getopt` supporting "long" option format for command line parameters like "--flag" rather than just "-f"), the tried and trusted UNIX/Linux facility `getopt()` can be used as in:

```
int c;
Config config = { 20, "plugins", 29.3, true };
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "m:n:s:v")) != EOF)
{
    switch (c)
    {
      case 'm': config.max_for_whatever_ = lexical_cast<int>(optarg); break;
      case 'n': config.name_for_whatever_ = optarg; break;
      case 'd': config.scaling_factor_for_whatever_ = lexical_cast<double>(optarg); break;
      case 'v': config.verbose_ ^= true; break;
      default:
        std::cerr << argv[0] << ": unsupported option '" << c << "' - exiting\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// then, use the configuration parameters directly by name...
```

The concepts are the same whether you're reading from a configuration file, command line arguments, some manner of registry: as you encounter specific configuration values try to write them into properly-typed and -named variables specific to their import in the code.

Comment: Well, yes, I probably over-engineered a simple thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't create separate classed for each of those things. They are not interchangable, you can't give an IntPreference sometimes that wants a StringPreference...  If you pass an abstract "Preference" to a function it's going to be expecting that to be a specific type in order to make use of the data.

I wouldn't create subsclasses at all here, I would have a Preference class that has separate functions getIntValue(), getStringValue() etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have a single interface if your preferences have different types of values. This is what comes to mind:

```
class IPreference
{
public:
  virtual ~IPreference() {};
  virtual void Parse( std::istream& s ) = 0;
  virtual void Serialize( std::ostream& s ) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Preference : public IPreference
{
public:
  const T& Get() const { return m_value; }
  void Set(const T& value) const { m_value = value; }
private:
  T m_value;
};
```

I would try to put as much logic in the base class as possible. But if you want to avoid type-polling I think you might need one class per property type here.

On a second thought, you might assume that all your property types support reading from/writing to std::streams. Then you could just go with templates and work with stringstream (if you read from strings).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use templates:

```
template <typename T>
class ChildPreference
{

    T parseFromString(std::string s) {
        //todo
    }    
    void set(T newVal) {
        //todo
    }                 
    // etc.                                   
}

ChildPreference<int> intObj;
ChildPreference<float> fltObj;
ChildPreference<std::string> strObj;
```

Note with templates you must define functions in place.

Answer (score 1):

*if Base declares a member function set(int x), and Derived declares a member function set(string c) (same name but different parameter types and/or constness), then the Base set(int x) is "hidden" rather than "overloaded" or "overridden" (even if the Base set(int x) is virtual)*

Your [Answer is in this link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned shadowing in my question, but thanks for pointing it out again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use templates, as suggested in a comment by Jacob S. It would look something like this:

```
template<class T>
class Preference
{
public:
    parseFromString(std::string s) = 0;
    T get() { /* some implementation */ }
    void set(T newValue) { /* some implementation */ }

private:
    T value_;
};
```

You would use it like:

```
Preference<int> intPrefs;
Preference<std::string> stringPrefs;
```

Comment: The problem starts when he wants to use it polymorphically, that's why I suggested type erause.

Comment: I considered templates, but, please, see my edit - how can I push them all in a hash table?